# replace a cube by a sphere in three.js with an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I have to replace the cube by a sphere with the input forme but if i add a function in the javascipt the cube disappears.

What do I have to do if I want to change the cube's dimensions?

I don't know how to link the function `modifie` with the three numeric inputs (`longueur`, `largeur`, `hauteur`) because as I've said before if I add on function, the cube disappears. The functions are wrong?

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr1r8dh0/)

```
function modifie(){
    var longueur ,
    var largeur,
    var profondeur.

     longueur =document.getElementById("longueur").value
     largeur =document.getElementById("largeur").value
     profondeur =document.getElementById ("profondeur").value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the new possibilities of CSS3. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/dy9negnm/)

```js
$("div").addClass("ball")
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  background-color: #3b4ba3;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}
div.ball {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -25px -25px 40px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);  
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```